# sap.m.Tree disable showing arrow icon on leaf item

Tags: tree, navigation, sapui5

I have a sap.m.Tree but without annotation hierarchy. I use the A_SalesOrder entity with expanded "to_Item" array for salesOrder.
The top level is SalesOrder (header) and the "to_Item" array is the array of leaf items for the salesOrder.
Because I do not have an annotation hierarchy format, I build the tree with items parameter navigation object:

```
                <Tree
                id="SC_SO_Tree"
                selectionChange="onSelectionChange"
                mode="MultiSelect"
                items="{path: 'SalesOrder>/A_SalesOrder',
                            parameters: {
                                operationMode: 'Default',
                                expand: 'to_Item',
                                countMode: 'Inline',
                                navigation: {
                                    'A_SalesOrder': 'to_Item'
                                }
                            }
                     
                     }"
            >
                <items>
                    <CustomTreeItem id="SC_SO_Tree_Custom">
                        <!-- <content> -->
                        <FlexBox
                            id="SC_FBT2"
                            alignItems="Start"
                            width="100%"
                            displayInline="false"
                        >
                            <items>
                                <Text ....
                                <Text ....
```

in the property

```
                                navigation: {
                                    'A_SalesOrder': 'to_Item'
                                }
```

it knows how to build the tree and adds a subnode for every item of salesOrder.

The problem is, it shows an ugly arrow on the leaf level of the tree.. and I don't know how to disable it. I guess the reason is because I use the navigation property... does anybody know how to disable that?

[image]